# Unexpected behaviour of empty line in Springer latex template

Tags: springer, springernature

I don't understand why in the below code it is necessary to have an empty line between `\abstract{...}` and the `\maketitle` command.

With an empty line there the below code compiles as expected, without it an empty pdf (or none at all) is output. I am using the latex template provided [here](https://www.springernature.com/de/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support).

Is this the expected behaviour? If so, why is it not compiling?

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[default,pdflatex]{sn-jnl}

\title{Test}
\author{...}

\begin{document}

\abstract{
    Abstract text here.
}

\maketitle


\section{Introduction}
Text here.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is by (terrible:-) design.

The class does.

```
\long\def\abstract#1 \par{\def\@abstract{%
\let\paragraph\subabstracthead%
\abstractfont%
\abstracthead*{\abstractname}%
#1\par}}%
```

Which means that the argument of `\abstract` is not given by `{...}` (you could remove the ones you used). Instead it is delimited by a literal space followed by a `\par` or blank line,

You could try complaining to Springer, although I suspect it would not change.

Comment: Thank you very much! This really is not the most intuitive design choice in my opinion…

Comment: @JonIsr er, yes. As I say you could ask that it is changed, but I wouldn't be that optimisic, publishers don't like changing things.

Comment: @JonIsr hmm just looked at the example document in the download and it does use  `\abstract{....}` syntax and doesn't mention that the braces can be omitted for 1-paragraph abstracts. So perhaps Springer could change this with no change to documented behaviour.